# Deleting Row in TableViewController - "unrecognized selector" crash

Tags: ios

I am attempting to delete two "products" in my tableView from a productArray property which is a MutableArray.

```
 [self.productsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

I am getting this error in the console:

> -[__NSArrayI removeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff6f850e410
>   2015-06-24 15:09:24.568 NavCtrl[17333:8660630] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI removeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff6f850e410'

Looking at the debugger it seems that the indexPath property is NULL.  I am guessing this is a good candidate for why my code is crashing, however I don't know why indexPath doesn't have the value of what the row I deleted.

Any help is appreciated and let me know if more info is needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
[__NSArrayI removeObjectAtIndex:]:  indicates that your array is not mutable!
```

Make sure if the array is mutable indeed. If it is, try to remove the cell first and then remove the object from the array.

Answer (score 0):

It's in?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

You can paste all code?

Try this to test:

```
NSIndexpath *idxPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.productsArray removeObjectAtIndex:idxPath];

    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[idxPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [tableView endUpdates];
```